# I'd like to get the values out of the for loop into one variable

Tags: php, text-files, phpexcel

I want to save the records that are in the for loop into a textfile (like I am trying to do below). But I don't understand how to get to X. I tried more things, but they don't seem to work. I tried this on a webserver ^

```
echo "<table>";
for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo ("rownumber is: ".$row);
}
echo "</table>";

file_put_contents('file.txt',X);
```

Comment: What is X in your case?

Comment: Save the data you want to store into a txt into a variabler like $test? and use file_put_contents('linklijst.txt',$test);

Comment: X should be everything that is stored in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the data in string and save it into the file.

```
$data = "<table>";
for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
    $data .= "<tr><td>";
      $data .=$worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
      $data .="</td><td>";
      $data .="rijnummer is: ".$row;
}
  $data .="</table>";
```

You won't see table in text file as it is for HTML only, you will see exact string.

```
file_put_contents('linklijst.txt',  $data);
```

Comment: You are the hero of the day! I changed it to 

echo "<table>";
for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    $data .= $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo ("rijnummer is: ".$row);
}
echo "</table>";

file_put_contents('linklijst.txt',$data);

So it works now :)